# Immigration to the UK and declaring goods

Tags: united-kingdom, customs

I'm soon relocating to the UK from a EU country on a work visa. I have a few questions in regard to this:

1. Do I need to declare electronic goods that I want to bring with me for personal use via the airport to the customs?

For example, I'll be bringing my laptop, phone, watch and headphones, and I believe that the price of laptop as well as the phone was over £390 back when I purchased them. I do know about ToR, but I'll quite likely be travelling before I can get approval on ToR (as it can take up to 2 weeks, but I have my flight in a week).

2. Is the limit of £390 per item, or is it for all the items?
3. If I declare the customs at the airport, how is the price of the goods calculated? I don't really have any proof of their value, as they were purchased a long time ago.